# Why is this simple javascript not doing anything?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AHd34/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var a = document.createTextNode('AAA');
$jA = $(a);
$('#listContainer').append(jA);
});

<body>

<div id="content">

    <div id="newLists" style="border:none;">
        <!-- I'm going to need to reorganize this css so the above line does not need to happen -->
        <p id="newListTitle"><span id="newListSpan">Here is a list </span></p>          
            <div id="listContainer">

            </div>      
    </div>

</div>
```

I've never used jsfiddle before and it seems to just not be working at all.  Probably something very simple and silly.

Comment: Sure seems to be doing something to me, `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'createTextElement' `

Comment: Opening that in Firefox (with Firebug installed) I get: `TypeError: document.createTextElement is not a function`. Perhaps you mean `document.createTextNode()`? You'll also need to use `$jA` as @jalynn2 pointed out.

Comment: You probably want `createTextNode` not `createTextElement`. Also, `append(jA)` should probably be `append($jA)`

Answer (score 3):

2 things:
first: in the console you can see that createTextElement doesn't exist
second: you declare a variable $jA and then append a variable jA (without the $).

Here's the working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/AHd34/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = document.createTextNode('AAA');
    $jA = $(a);
    $('#listContainer').append($jA);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var a =document.createElement("a"); 
        a.innerHTML="AAA";

        $('#listContainer').append(a);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AHd34/7/